# The pager is not working as expected in jqGrid with a JSON

Tags: json, jsp, jqgrid, pager

I have a question about jqGrid and Json.

This is the code of my jsp file with the code of Jquery:

```
    <body >

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jq(function() {
            jq("#grid").jqGrid({
                url:'/test-security-client/crud',
                datatype: 'json',
                mtype: 'GET',
                colNames:['Id', 'Log Message'],
                colModel:[
                    {name:'id',index:'id', width:55,editoptions:{readonly:true,size:10},hidden:true},
                    {name:'logMsg',index:'logMsg', width:300,editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:10}}
                ],
                rowNum:20,
                rowList:[20,40,60],
                height: 450,
                autowidth: true,
                rownumbers: true,
                pager: '#pager',
                sortname: 'id',
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: "asc",
                caption:"Error Logs",
                emptyrecords: "Empty records",
                loadonce: false,
                loadComplete: function() {
                },
                jsonReader : {
                    root: "rows",
                    page: "page",
                    total: "total",
                    records: "records",
                    repeatitems: false,
                    cell: "cell",
                    id: "id"
                }
            });

            jq("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',
                    {edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:false},
                    { },
                    { },
                    { }, 
                    { 
                        sopt:['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'gt', 'cn', 'bw', 'ew'],
                        closeOnEscape: true, 
                            multipleSearch: true, 
                            closeAfterSearch: true }
            );

            jq("#grid").navButtonAdd('#pager',
                {   caption:"Delete", 
                    buttonicon:"ui-icon-trash", 
                    onClickButton: deleteRow,
                    position: "last", 
                    title:"", 
                    cursor: "pointer"
                } 
            );

            jq("#btnFilter").click(function(){
                jq("#grid").jqGrid('searchGrid',
                        {multipleSearch: false, 
                            sopt:['eq']}
                );
            });

        });
    </script>
   ...
```

And this is the JSON that I am sending:

```
{"total":"2","page":"1","records":"28","rows":[{"id":1,"logMsg":"ID of log:1-Requesting authentication. (SMA/SmaAdmin/password)"},{"id":2,"logMsg":"ID of log:2-Authentication received."},{"id":3,"logMsg":"ID of log:3-Test"},{"id":4,"logMsg":"ID of log:4-Test 2"},{"id":5,"logMsg":"ID of log:5-Test 3"},{"id":6,"logMsg":"ID of log:6-Test 4"},{"id":7,"logMsg":"ID of log:7-Test 5"},{"id":8,"logMsg":"ID of log:8-Test 6"},{"id":9,"logMsg":"ID of log:9-Test 7"},{"id":10,"logMsg":"ID of log:10-Test 8"},{"id":11,"logMsg":"ID of log:11-Test 9"},{"id":12,"logMsg":"ID of log:12-Test 10"},{"id":13,"logMsg":"ID of log:13-Test 11"},{"id":14,"logMsg":"ID of log:14-Test 12"},{"id":15,"logMsg":"ID of log:15-Test 13"},{"id":16,"logMsg":"ID of log:16-Test 14"},{"id":17,"logMsg":"ID of log:17-Test 15"},{"id":18,"logMsg":"ID of log:18-Test 16"},{"id":19,"logMsg":"ID of log:19-Test 17"},{"id":20,"logMsg":"ID of log:20-Test 18"},{"id":21,"logMsg":"ID of log:21-Test 19"},{"id":22,"logMsg":"ID of log:22-Test 20"},{"id":23,"logMsg":"ID of log:23-Test 21"},{"id":24,"logMsg":"ID of log:24-Test 22"},{"id":25,"logMsg":"ID of log:25-Test 23"},{"id":26,"logMsg":"ID of log:26-Test 24"},{"id":27,"logMsg":"ID of log:27-Test 25"},{"id":28,"logMsg":"ID of log:28-Test 26"}]}
```

HERE IS MY QUESTION: This code is working, the jqgrid is well displayed, all the information is comming well. BUT the pager is not working well. Because, I can't move between pages. (I have 2 pages, and I start the jqGrid in the page number 1.. but I cant go to the number 2).

If I change the property loadonce to true.. then Is working. But I dont want to use this property, and all the records are comming in wrong positions.

As I understand the JSON is right, and the code is right, I dont know what I am doing wrong. (I am new to jqGrid and JQuery). I guess that I have one kind of problem with the pager.

Any idea of what I am doing wrong? Do I have to send a Json with the information of each page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You JSON is correct as JSON, but it's not corresponds to the data requested by jqGrid. Let us I explain this.

You have `rowNum: 20`, `sortname: 'id'`, `sortorder: "asc"`. At the beginning (at the first filling of the grid) jqGrid send to your server at the URL `'/test-security-client/crud'` the request having `page=1&rows=20&sidx=id&sord=asc` at the end of the URL: `/test-security-client/crud?page=1&rows=20&sidx=id&sord=asc`. It means that in the response from the server you should include *only first 20 items from the result set sorted by `id`*. So you have to sort the result set by `id` (see `sidx=id` and `sord=asc` -  `ORDER BY id`) and then get the first page (`page=1`) where the size of the page is 20 (`rows=20` - `SELECT (TOP 20)`).

You current response from the server includes all 28 of the result set. For the first page it's not critical, but I suppose that the response on request of the second page contains the same 28 items instead of only the last 8 items (the sorting is very important to get correct 8 items).

If you would fix the problem in your server code the grid will display correct data on changing of the page.

Comment: I guess that you are right. THANKS! for the explanation. Now I understand my error. I will implement the solution then I am going to post an example of what I did. But, yes... the JSON is correct, but the data in the JSON is not acurate. I should send each page with the records for that page only. Thanks again.

Comment: Well I already solve the problem. And I found a very good tutorial that explain a nice way to solve this problem. So I am not going to post my code, since I followed the other.. with my modifications :) The link for this tutorial is: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/07/jqgrid-rest-ajax-spring-mvc-integration.html